# Updating linux-firmware:amd to 1.7 causes Kubuntu to freeze on boot

Tags: boot, kubuntu, amdgpu

I'm running kubuntu 23.04 with an AMD RX 7900 XTX. Today, when I upgraded linux-firmware:amd from 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.6 to 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.7, my computer would freeze on boot. I then booted into safe mode and downgraded from 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.7 to 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.2 which fixed my issues.
Has anyone encountered this besides me?

Answer (score 1):

same problem kubuntu 23.04 only i have AMD RX 7900 XT,
at the time of update Kernel version: 6.2.0-34,
since it was the first time I made such a recovery, I supplement it with a simple instruction,
this displays a list of available versions

```
apt policy linux-firmware
```

we get a list

```
    linux-firmware:
  Installed: 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.7
  Candidate: 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.7
  Version table:
 *** 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.7 500
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security/main i386 Packages
     20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main i386 Packages
```

and install the required version

```
apt install  linux-firmware=20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been addressed with linux-firmware=20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.8

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/2038745